# (Swift) Adding Pinned Navigation Bar to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionView that scrolls with a bunch of images and I want to have a pinned Navigation Bar on the top that stays there even as you scroll.  I moved the cell down in the UICollectionView in order to make room for a navigation bar and I dragged one into the View.  I can see it in my story board however it is just a black view when I run the app.  Can anyone please show me how to make this nav bar appear and how to make it stay pinned at the top even as you scroll.  Thank you so so much. (I tried to attach photos of my problem but it says I do not have enough reputation to post images)  I hope you guys are able to understand my problem and direct me in a way in which I could add a navigation bar that stays pinned on the top of a CollectionViewController

Answer (score 1):

1. Drag a navigation controller into your storyboard. You probably want to position it just to the left of the view controller that has the collection view.
2. Delete the view controller that Xcode automatically attaches to the navigation controller.
3. Right click on the navigation controller and drag from root view controller over to your view controller where you have your collection view.
4. If necessary, move all segues that went to the collection view to the navigation controller instead.

Comment: I might have made it confusing in my question: I have two collectionview's  - The first collection view has a bunch of general image categories and then the second collectionview has all the images of the selected image category from the first collection view. I want the nav bar in the second collection view so I can go back to the first.  Please let me know if that doesnt make sense.  Thank you so much!

Comment: So there are two separate view controllers with collection views? I would put the navigation controller prior to the first collection view. You will have the navigation bar at the top of the first and this navigation bar will stay there when you push to the next view controller. The navigation bar will automatically add a back button when you push to the second view controller.

Comment: Correct.. I have the first collection view activate a segue to the second collection view when an item in the first is selected.  I would be willing to put a navigation bar in the first collection view but I am just stumped on how to do so.  When I select it I make room in the "header" section for the nav bar and then place it in the story board but when it loads in the simulator I just see a blank black space where I made the room for the nav bar.. not the actual nav bar.  Here are images of the story board and what actually shows:
http://i.imgur.com/k0Iyj6d.png
http://i.imgur.com/ZfXhkjt.jpg

Comment: Don't put a navigation bar in the view controller, hook up an actual navigation controller. Put the navigation controller before the first view controller with the collection view and set that view controller with the collection view to be the navigation controller's root view controller. Look at the directions above if you're having trouble.

Comment: Ok I think im getting what you are saying.  Would I delete the root view controller in the image I include at the end of this and then link that navigation controller to the first collection view.  Hopefully this photo allows you to see what im working with more.
http://i.imgur.com/DeHV70q.png
Thank you again so so much.

Comment: Yep, exactly! Be sure to link the tab bar controller to the navigation controller instead of the trending view controller too.

Comment: Wait I got it to work! Only thing is how do I connect the second collection view to have the tab bar?? This is what I have now 
http://i.imgur.com/43UuREW.png
How do I get that second collection view to have that nav bar and then a back button and so on!?  Youve been so helpful thank you!

Comment: I think you have to redo the segue to the second collection view in the storyboard. You need to 1. Hook up a new segue that pushes and 2. Remove the original segue.

Comment: I did that and it worked... I can edit the title and everything but it doesnt show up in the simulator on the second collection view. But as you can tell from this photo it has the nav bar in both the collectionviews
http://i.imgur.com/hA2xLV4.png